# find the limit of ${(n + 1)^{{1 \over {\sqrt n }}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I really tried to think of a way to find the limit of this sequence but couldn't think of something useful. I tried to use Bernoulli's inequality to squeeze the sequence, but it didn't come in handy.

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {(n + 1)^{{1 \over {\sqrt n }}}} = ?$$

Comment: Does taking the logarithm clear it up?

Comment: As $n\to\infty$ or $n\to 0$?

Comment: I cannot use log, for we didn't reached that in our class.

Comment: @DavidJack How did you define exponentiation then...?

Comment: In some cases we used Bernoulli's inequality to get away from the exponent, In others we used other principles and theorems which doesn't invlove $log$.

Comment: You still haven't given us a complete problem. Is $n\to 0$ or $n\to\infty$?

Comment: oh sorry, to $\infty$

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without logarithms. First' a lemma:

**Lemma:** For an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \geq n_0$ we have $$n^\frac{1}{n} < 1 + \varepsilon.$$

To prove the lemma, note that the inequality is equivalent to $$ n < (1 + \varepsilon)^n,$$ and this is true when $n$ is large enough by binomial expansion.

Now, all the terms in your sequence are greater than $1$. You can use this, the lemma above, and the definition of limits to prove that the sequence converges to $1$.

Comment: Great! how did you think about it?

Comment: @DavidJack This is what you inevitably come to if you try to prove using only definitions that $n^{1/n}$ converges to $1$. But I knew that it converges to $1$ in advance, by taking the logarithm. So I used logarithms implicitly to find the answer, but excluded them from the "official" reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

It converges to $1$

firstly you see

$(1+n)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} \geq 1$

For the other bound

$$ (1+n)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} \leq  (1+n)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} \leq (2n)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}$$

you know that $2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n} } \rightarrow 1  $

For the other part you can use $\rm{AM-GM}$
$$ n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\leq ({\underbrace {1 \cdot 1 \ldots 1}_{[\sqrt n]-3}} \cdot n^{\frac{1}{3} }\cdot n^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot n^{\frac{1}{3}})^{\frac{1}{[\sqrt n]}} \leq  \frac{  [\sqrt n]-3 +3n^{\frac{1}{3}}}{ [\sqrt n]}\rightarrow 1$$
Where $[\cdot]$ is the integral part.